# Run Scala Program with Spark on Hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-compute-engine

i have create a scala program that search a word in a text file.
I create the file scala with eclipse and after i compile and create a jar with sbt and sbt assembly.After that i run the .jar with Spark in local and it run correctly.
Now i want try to run this program using Spark on hadoop, i have 1 master and 2 work machine.
I have to change the code ? and what command i do with the shell of the master?
i have create a bucket and i have put the text file in hadoop

this is my code:

```
    import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object wordcount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      // set spark context
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordcount").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

      val distFile = sc.textFile("bible.txt")

      print("Enter word to look for in the HOLY BILE: ")
      val word = Console.readLine
      var count = 0;
      var finalCount=0;
      println("You entered " + word)
      val input = sc.textFile("bible.txt")
      val splitedLines = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                    .filter(x => x.equals(word))

System.out.println("The word " + word + " appear " + splitedLines.count())
    }
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: change your program,  use master as indicating on spark master UI like `spark://xyz-server:7077`, or its better to don't set master in your program then you don't need to change your code, just tell master upon running the code in shell by parameter as `--master local`

Comment: the command that i try to use on shell in the master is spark-submit --master local --jars wordcount.jar? i put the jar file in folder of spark in the master, it is correct?

Comment: let me tell you how I do this. 1 - I don't mention spark master in my code.
2. I use following command to run my spark applications on cluster mode.
`spark-submit --class full.path.to.MainClass --master spark://cloud-server:7077 path_to_my_JAR.jar`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but what you mean whit full.path.to.MainClass?

Comment: full path mean, your package path, that is you defined in your jar.

Comment: Its fully qualified name of class for example. `com.xyz.platform.MainClass` including package

Comment: In my case it is com.wordcount ? is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following line,

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordcount").setMaster("local[*]")
```

to

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordcount")
```

This will allow you not to modify the code whenever you want to switch from local mode to cluster mode. The master option can be passed via the spark-submit command as follows,

```
spark-submit --class wordcount  --master <master-url> --jars wordcount.jar
```

and if you want to run your program locally, use the following command,

```
spark-submit --class wordcount  --master local[*] --jars wordcount.jar
```

[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) is the list of master option that you can set while running the application.

Comment: i have try your solution in local and it return the error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or phyton file). Where i specify this type?

Comment: spark-submit --class wordcount  --master local[*] --jars wordcount.jar <primary JAR file>

Comment: i have create only 1 jar with sbt that i call wordcount.jar, what you mean with primary JAR file?

Comment: yes, then run like this, spark-submit --class wordcount --master local[*] wordcount.jar

Comment: I have tried to launch it on the worker machine with spark-submit --class wordcount --master yarn-cluster wordcount.jar but it return this error :                                    15/06/11 09:16:30 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-m-on8g/10.240.180.15:8032
15/06/11 09:16:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-m-on8g/10.240.180.15:8032. Already tried 0 
time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)